Show that for any $A\in\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ with $1>\mu(A)=a>0$ and any $b\in [0,a]$ so that $\mu(B)=b$.
Let $([0,1], \mathcal{B}([0,1]), \mu)$ be a measure space with Lebesgue measure. Show that for any $A\in\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ with $1>\mu(A)=a>0$ and any $b\in [0,a]$ there exists $\mathcal{B}([0,1]) \ni B \subset A$ so that $\mu(B)=b$.

My idea is that define $f(t):=m(A\cap [-t,t])$ for $t>0$. Clearly, $f(t)$ is uniformly continuous and increasing on $[0,1]$.
We have $\lim_{t\to o^+}f(t)=0$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=m(A)=a$.
By intermediate value theorem, there exists $t_0\in (0,\infty)$ so that $f(t_0)=b$ for some $0\le b\le a$. And $B:=A\cap [-t_0,t_0]$ is the desired set.
Does this proof look good?

Yes, except replace the $\infty$ with a $1$.
